# I need proper syntax for "if and" statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need Google Sheets formula for if cell h5 is blank and cell b5 is not blank if true then d5 if false ""s 
This is what I came up with, but it does not work.

```
=if(and(isblank(H5),not(isblank(B5),D5,"")))
```

Comment: you missed a parenthesis: should be `not(isblank(B5))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(and(isblank(H5),not(isblank(B5))), D5, "")
```

**Syntax is** `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

**AND** Function is `AND(logical_expression1, [logical_expression2, ...])`

Comment: Perfect...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((H5="")*(B5<>""); D5; )
```

for arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((H5:H="")*(B5:B<>""); D5:D; ))
```